# How do I use the third argument in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main {
int a; 
for (int i=0; i<a; i+7){
      i++;
   }
}
```

Why can't I use the i+7 in this for loop? (I am not sure how to make this for loop so that it can add seven each time it iterates instead of by one time).

Comment: What is `i+7` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to declare `a`
2. You need to declare `i`
3. The third argument: `i=i+7` (as noted by *Michael*, this can also be expressed as: `i+=7`)

It should be:

```
int i, a = 21;        //choose some value for a
for (i=0; i < a; i=i+7)
```

Also, i dont know why you are doing `i++` inside the loop... i think you are mixing for and while loops.

Comment: So can I do this: int i, a; cin >> a; for (i=10; i<a; i=i+7)

Comment: @MichaelPliskin I agree with you, but it seems that the OP have some troubles with syntax... so maybe i=i+7 is better for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

for loop has three parts

1. Initialization
2. Condition
3. Post-Iteration (Increment,Decrement or something else)

> for(Initialization; Condtion; Post-Iteration)

You need to understand the flow. `Initizalition` will happen just once. The `condition` will be checked before entering the body every time, and after every iteration the control will go to `post-iteration`. In `post-iteration` you can do a number of things depending on your requirement. You can either increment/decrement(traditional usage) or you can call a function as well or leave it blank.

**Example:**

```
int i=0;
for( ; ; ){
   i++;
   if(i==10) break;
}
```